# Solving a Partial Differential Equation written with transformation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have what I imagine is the simplest partial differential equation one could ask for but I'm uncertain how its solved. 
We are initially told $u(x,t) = f(\chi,\tau)$ where $\chi = x +bt$ and $\tau = t$. We also have an initial condition where $u(x,0) = x +1$.

I was able to rewrite the initial complicated PDE of $u(x,t)$ as:

$$ \frac {\partial f}{\partial \tau} + bf = 0 $$

I want to solve for $f(\chi,\tau)$ and then get the general solution for $u(x,t)$. My initial idea was to solve with simple integration, which gave me 
$$f(\chi,\tau) = e^{-b\tau} + C(\chi)  $$

I don't know how to solve for the constant term with $\chi$, but I would think it would require an initial condition. Thus, I have to get $u(x,t)$ and then use the initial condition given. But how does one write $u(x,t)$ without knowing what $C(\chi)$ is?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$f(\chi,\tau)=e^{-b\tau}+C(\chi)$

You know

$\chi=x+bt,\tau=t,u(x,t)=f(\chi,\tau)$

Substitute things now,
$$u(x,t)=e^{-b[t]}+C([x+bt])$$

Your initial condition is: $u(x,0)=x+1$, so
$$u(x,0)=e^{-b\cdot0}+C(x+b\cdot0)=1+C(x)=x+1\rightarrow C(x)=x$$

Therefore,
$u(x,t)=e^{-bt}+x$.

Is that it?

Comment: Shouldn't it  be $u(x,t)=e^{-bt}+x+bt$ in your final answer. ?